# What is causing the space between inline block elements?

Tags: css

On [this page](http://roofspan.madhatmedia.com.au/example1.html), when you hover over a navigation item, there is a gap to the left of it:

[image]

Can you help me to remove this gap please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **`display:block`** instead of **`display:inline-block`** then add **`float:left`** for inline elements

> **`display:inline-block`** add extra spaces in px when you write code in beauty
>   mode with spaces and line's

something like this:

```
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To solve your issue. Try to float all the `li` elements inside `ul` which remove the magical margin between each `li`. (screenshot below is the aftereffect)

[image]

> The reason you get the spaces is because, well, you have spaces between the elements (a line break and a few tabs counts as a space, just to be clear).

**To Solve This Issue in General**

1. Remove the spaces
2. Use negative margin
3. Skip closing tag (Hack)
4. Set font-size to 0
5. Use float
6. Use flexbox

Read more about the magical space for inline items,

https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/